# ASP.NET web forms user control with DropDownList's SelectedIndex cannot be set

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms, selectedindex

I have created a web forms user control with a DropDownList. I want to change `SelectedIndex` property of `DropDownList1` to change the selected index.

**WebUserControl1.ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.ControlUI.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**WebUserControl1.ascx.cs:**

```
using System;
namespace WebApplication1.ControlUI
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (IsPostBack) return;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add("Test: " + i.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void SetSelectedIndex(int index) {
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am using the user control in a page.

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/ControlUI/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" id="WebUserControl1" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            WebUserControl1.SetSelectedIndex(3);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work. It assigns *-1* into `SelectedIndex` property of `DropDownList1`. But the user control works if I add items into the DropDownList in the markup (`WebUserControl1.ascx`), rather than in the codebehind file (`WebUserControl1.ascx.cs`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.ControlUI.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Test: 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test: 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test: 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test: 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test: 5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

But I need to add items using the codebehind file, not in the markup file. Why it is not working? How to solve the problem?

Comment: you want to add items from code behind or you want to set selectedindex from code behind?

Comment: @DSA: Both. I want to add items from code behind like `DropDownList1.Items.Add("item name")` and then change `SelectedIndex` by `WebUserControl1.SetSelectedIndex(number)` in a page's code behind like `Default.aspx.cs`.

Comment: Here is your solution: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=155

Comment: @DSA: `SelectedIndex` still cannot be changed by the approach (`public DropDownList ControlB_DDL`) described in the link. The article in the link is for a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Page_Load` for the page containing the user control (Default) executes **before** `Page_Load` for the user control (WebUserControl1). Therefore, when `SetSelectedIndex` is invoked from the page, the drop down does not have any list item in it when the page is first built.

You can solve the issue very simply by creating the list item for the drop down in the `Init` stage of the user control life cycle rather than in the `Load` stage:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (IsPostBack) return;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Test: " + i.ToString());
  }
}
```